# How can I use variable to set row name in stored procedure sql-server

Tags: sql-server

I need use the variable to set the name row but I have erreur

```
CREATE 
PROCEDURE dbo.procedure (@var int)  
AS  
  SELECT row_name as @var
  FROM table  
  ...
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you tell us the error?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for this. Why do you need to dynamically allow naming the column? This seems like something that should be done in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: `@var`, here, is of type `int`. It doesn't contain a name itself, it is the name of the parameter. If you wanted the column to literally be named `@var` as well (for whatever strange reason), that's possible: escape it as `[@var]`. If you need an actual dynamic column name, see Sean's remarks. If your column names are actually numbers, though, the whole thing smacks of something ill-advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using Dynamic SQL. Something Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
(
  @ColNm VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT
      @Qry = 'SELECT '+@ColNm+' = Col_Name FROM YourTable'

   EXEC(@Qry)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this Sample script, i have use sample table in procedure,The input value through variable will be a alias column name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_procedure (@var int)
AS
Begin
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)

SET @Sql='
SELECT EmployementStatus AS '+ QUOTENAME(CAST(@var AS VARCHAr(10)))+'
 from [dbo].[EmployeeInfo]'
 --Print @Sql
 EXEC (@Sql)

END


EXEC Usp_procedure @var=1
```

Result

```
1
-------
Intern
Jr. DBA
```